# Updating data in SQL Database using PHP and HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to create a form that will update my database. 
I want the user to select name from the list and then enter the new values, on submission, in the table, the name will be modified which is selected.

FORM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

      <html>
     <head>
<title>Logging | Warriors Elite</title>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
 </head>

      <body><h1>Update Opposition War Details</h1>
          <form method = "post" action = "updateopponent.php">
 <p>Player Name: <select name="Name">

<?

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","pswd");

    if (!$con)
 {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select database
mysql_select_db("978947") or die(mysql_error());

        $cdquery="SELECT Name FROM opponent";
        $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());

        while ($cdrow=mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
        $cdTitle=$cdrow["Name"];
            echo "<option>
                $cdTitle
            </option>";

        }

        ?>
 </select>
</p>

<p>Clan Best Attacker
<input placeholder='#. Name' type='text' name='CBA' id='CBA' />
</p>


<p>Percentage(%)
<input type='text' name='percent' id='percent' />
</p>


<p>Stars Achieved
<input type='text' name='star' id='star' />
</p>

<button id='insert'>Submit</button>

<p id='result'></p>
</form>
        <?php
     }
  ?>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
      define('HOST','localhost');
   define('USERNAME', 'db');
   define('PASSWORD','pswd');
  define('DB','');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);


     $sql="UPDATE opponent SET Clan Best attack='".$_POST['CBA']."', Stars Achieved='".$_POST['star']."', Damage percentage='".$_POST['percent']."'         WHERE   Name='".intval($_REQUEST['Name'])."'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql)or 
        die ("this stuffedup");

        mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

I am able to connect to database but on clicking submit it fails(This stuffedup)

Comment: Deprecated & removed functions again!

Comment: `<button id='insert'>Submit</button>` that does nothing unless you're using JS/Ajax, which you're not.

Comment: Then you're attempting to connect with the `mysqli_` MySQL API, but later using `mysql_`, and those do **NOT** intermix.

Comment: then these column names `Clan Best attack` -`Stars Achieved` - `Damage percentage` contain spaces and will throw a syntax error. edit: `mysql_close($conn);` referencing an undefined variable.

Comment: Instead of using `die ("this stuffedup");` try using `die(mysql_error())` you'll know where exactly you're going wrong.

Comment: In short, your code is a mess. Do spend some time reading and understanding how syntax works and SQL.

Comment: Thanx guys, it worked on re-writing it by keeping the points given by you in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use whitespaces in column names without back ticking them:

```
$sql = "
UPDATE opponent
SET `Clan Best attack`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CBA']) . "', 
    `Stars Achieved`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['star']) . "', 
    `Damage percentage`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['precent']) . "'         
WHERE `Name`='" . intval($_REQUEST['Name']) . "'
";
```

btw: mysql is very outdated. You want to use mysqli instead.
btw2: you may also want to protect your database from injections. e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $userInput)

Comment: True, however that is but "one" of many problems in their code. Do go over my comments (again, if you have already) under their question. Just this won't fix this, but is a start.

Comment: @Lorenzo Belfanti  your suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11493075 clearly is breaking the answer. The ticks MUST be included here. I rejected the edit. Whoever approves this, will hear from me/mods.

Comment: Your edit: that will only work if the OP is using the `mysqli_` throughout their entire code. They are presently mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_`. Remember to indent code with 4 spaces. I had to re-edit again.